# Label in Update panel does not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

I have a `Update panel` in `Master page`, and have a label and `button` in the content page,, when i `click` on the `button` and assign some text to `label` , the value set to label does not reflect, i think the issue due to update panel in `Master page`, can anyone help?

**In Master Page**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**In Content Page**

Comment: How are you assigning the text to the label, could you provide some code?

Comment: Why do you assume that the UpdatePanel causes this issue, where is the UpdatePanel on the MasterPage?

Comment: Not cleary explained..

Comment: @Haden693: I updated the question, hope it is much clear now thanks

Comment: @Darshan: I Updated to question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my Problem, I am posting here may be it will help someone

Add the `asp:PostBackTrigger` in update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
       </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ContentPlaceHolder1" />
   </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for upvote, Please also update my question too. If its useful for anyone